# Relieving letter and joining issue

Tags: india, relieving-letter

I have reported in to company at their Bangalore location. But I didn't realise that they might consider it as 'joining' the company, as there was no work on that day. Now, on the second day, I informed them to cancel my joining as they told me I joined them. Now they took resignation letter from me but didn't provide a relieving letter. They told me that I will get it after 2 months only. So I just took the copy of my resignation letter which I submitted to them.

I am now joining the company at my home state. Is there any problem here ?

Comment: What is your exact concern? The question seems unclear. Some companies do have a weird policy of providing relieving letter after 1-2 months.

Comment: Do you have their acceptance of your resignation? And yeah, as @ShaunakD - mentioned, some companies do have that weird policy. So till you get your actual relieving letter, you can use the mail I mentioned.

Comment: Did you fill out any paperwork with the new company?  In the US you have several documents that you have to fill out to be considered employed, I would expect something similar in India.

Comment: Is there a reason that you cannot simply ignore that company and use the relieving letter from your previous employer as proof of eligibility for future employment?

Answer (score 1):

Why company staff asked for resignation, did you sign the offer letter? If yes then why did you sign it when you didn't want to join. 
Even if you did so, then there shouldn't be any concern. 
Its totally "null n void" because relieving letter also acts as experience letter. Nothing added in your experience years/days, any record maintained anywhere, any account opened, any salary transferred, nothing.
Even new company would not ask where were you that day, if they ask (I doubt how they know) explain everything. 

You have encountered a mad company, this is only your bad luck if new company also asks for relieving letter of what has happened there. And trust me if you have talent don't work for such mad/bully employers.

In the end technically, logically your record, your resume is clean.

*To understand the actual purpose of relieving letter read bulleted points in answer [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/33925/preventing-abuse-in-countries-where-relieving-letters-are-the-norm/36936#36936).*